# Pyspark extract all that comes after the second period

Tags: python, regex, string, pyspark, substring

I am looking to create a new column that contains all characters after the second last occurrence of the '.' character.

If there are less that two '.' characters, then keep the entire string.

I am looking to do this in spark 2.4.8 without using a UDF. Any ideas?

```
data = [
('google.com',),
('asdasdasd.google.com',),
('a.d.a.google.com',),        
('www.google.com',)
]

df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF(['host'])
df.withColumn('domain', functions.regexp_extract(df['host'], r'\b\w+\.\w+\b', 0)).show()
+--------------------+----------------+
|                host|          domain|
+--------------------+----------------+
|          google.com|      google.com|
|asdasdasd.google.com|asdasdasd.google|
|    a.d.a.google.com|             a.d|
|      www.google.com|      www.google|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

The desired result is the following.

```
+--------------------+----------------+
|                host|          domain|
+--------------------+----------------+
|          google.com|      google.com|
|asdasdasd.google.com|      google.com|
|    a.d.a.google.com|      google.com|
|      www.google.com|      google.com|
+--------------------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `substring_index`.

```
df.withColumn('domain', f.substring_index('host', '.', -2)).show(truncate=False)

+--------------------+----------+
|host                |domain    |
+--------------------+----------+
|google.com          |google.com|
|asdasdasd.google.com|google.com|
|a.d.a.google.com    |google.com|
|www.google.com      |google.com|
+--------------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First use the `split` function to split the string into an array, then use the `slice` function to slice the **last two elements**, and finally use `array_join` to connect the two elements.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

...
df = df.withColumn('domain', F.array_join(F.slice(F.split('host', '\\.'), -2, 2), '.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check for a `.` character with `"\."` and "not a `.` character" with `[^\.]`. Combining that with `$` marking the "end of string", we can get the last two `.` (use the re.MULTILINE flag if you want to accept end of line too). However, since it is possible that there is only one `.` in the string, we can specify an "optional lookbehind" with `(?<=\.)?`.

```
import re
data = [
('google.com',),
('asdasdasd.google.com',),
('a.d.a.google.com',),        
('www.google.com',)
]

#using an optional lookback so that if there is only one '.' like in the first example it will still accept
regex = re.compile(r"(?<=\.)?[^\.]*\.[^\.]*$")
for item in data:
    string = item[0]
    match = regex.search(string)
    if match:
        start, end = match.span(0)
        print(string[:start], string[start:end], sep="//")

#output
//google.com
asdasdasd.//google.com
a.d.a.//google.com
www.//google.com
```

You can also do `match.group(0)` to get the matched string. In this example that would be `"google.com"`. The print in my example code is mostly to show where the split occurs.

Something to note is that if there is no `.` at all, this regex won't work. The regex if you want to accept a string without a `.` at all would instead be `(?<=\.)?[^\.]*(\.)?[^\.]*$`. There's also one which considers newline markers if you do want to use the re.MULTILINE flag which is `(?<=\.)?[^\.\n]*(\.)?[^\.\n]*$`. Here's a [[regexr link to test it]](https://regexr.com/78v00).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am looking to do this in Pyspark though!